# C++ Linked List remove all

Tags: c++, memory-management, data-structures, linked-list, removeall

So this is a bit of a conceptual question. I'm writing a LinkedList in C++, and as Java is my first language, I start to write my removeAll function so that it just joins the head an the tail nodes (I'm using sentinel Nodes btw). But I instantly realize that this won't work in C++ because I have to free the memory for the Nodes!

Is there some way around iterating through the entire list, deleting every element manually?

Comment: nope, for each `malloc` of a node, you'll need a `free`.

Comment: yeah I didn't think so....wishful thinking

Comment: Would smart pointers work here?

Comment: How are you identifying the sentinel nodes? @dreamlax yes, though the sentinels may complicate things a bit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make each node own the next one, i.e. be responsible for destroying it when it is destroyed itself. You can do this by using a smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr`:

```
struct node {
    // blah blah
    std::unique_ptr<node> next;
};
```

Then you can just destroy the first node and all the others will be accounted for: they will all be destroyed in a chain reaction of unique_ptr destructors.

If this is a doubly-linked list, you should not use `unique_ptr`s in both directions, however. That would make each node own the next one, and be owned by the next one! You should make this ownership relation exist only in one direction. In the other use regular non-owning pointers: `node* previous;`

However, this will not work as is for the sentinel node: it should not be destroyed. How to handle that depends on how the sentinel node is identified and other properties of the list.

If you can tell the sentinel node apart easily, like, for example, checking a boolean member, you can use a custom deleter that avoids deleting the sentinel:

```
struct delete_if_not_sentinel {
    void operator()(node* ptr) const {
        if(!ptr->is_sentinel) delete ptr;
    }
};

typedef std::unique_ptr<node, delete_if_not_sentinel> node_handle;

struct node {
    // blah blah
    node_handle next;
};
```

This stops the chain reaction at the sentinel.

Comment: That is the perfect way to do it! I overrode the == and != operator in my Nodes and they include checking the addresses of the next and prev Node pointers. The sentinel Nodes are the only ones that should have any 0 valued pointers so that should take care of the sentinel node issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like Java if you used a c++ [garbage collector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29).  Not many do.  In any case, it saves you at most a constant factor in running time, as you spend the cost to allocate each element in the list anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Well, sort of...  If you implement your list to use a memory pool then it is responsible for all data in that pool and the entire list can be deleted by deleting the memory pool (which may contain one or more large chunks of memory).

When you use memory pools, you generally have at least one of the following considerations:

- limitations on how your objects are created and destroyed;
- limitations on what kind of data you can store;
- extra memory requirements on each node (to reference the pool);
- a simple, intuitive pool versus a complex, confusing pool.

I am no expert on this.  Generally when I've needed fast memory management it's been for memory that is populated once, with no need to maintain free-lists etc.  Memory pools are much easier to design and implement when you have specific goals and design constraints.  If you want some magic bullet that works for all situations, you're probably out of luck.